# I cannot scroll down all the way on my site

Tags: html, css

I have a div element with all of my content in it, including a video at the bottom of the page. My issue is, when I try to scroll down to see the video, it only reaches about half of it, and refuses to scroll down any further.

```
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="shortcut icon" href="Images/favicon.ico" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Style.css" media="screen" />
    <title>Arthur</title>
    <meta content="text/html" charset="windows-1251">
    </head>
<Body background="Images/background2.jpg">
<A Href="main.html"><IMG class="imgborder" src="Images/button.png" align="left" height="50"></A>
<div id="wrapper" style="background-color:black; width:60%; margin-left: auto ; margin-right: auto ;">





<center><img width="60%" src="Images/logo2.png"></center>
<BR><BR>
<center><img class="imgborder" height="300" src="Images/muller.jpg"></center>
<Font size="5" color="crimson" face="Calibri">

<Center><P align="justify">... </P>

<P align="justify">...</P>

<P align="justify">...</P></Font></Center>



<Center><iframe width="640" height="360" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/DooYpt9Gu1s" frameborder="5" 
allowfullscreen></iframe></Center>
<Font size="5" color="crimson" face="Calibri"><P>Thomas Muller</P></font>



</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here's the CSS:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document*/

/*This section is for links*/
a:link
{
font-weight:normal; color:crimson
}
a:visited
{
font-weight:normal; color:Crimson;
}
a:hover
{
font-weight:bold; color: Royalblue; font-variant:small-caps;
}
/*This section is for a paragraph section*/
p {
font-style:normal; font-size:18px;
}
blue {
color:crimson;
}
/*This section is for the image's black border.*/
.imgborder {
border-color: crimson; border:thick; border-style:outset;
}
.body
{
background-color: #0000FF;
}
html , body{height:100%;}
#wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 990px;
    height:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
}

#navigation {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 990px;
    height: 55px;
    background-color: #fff;

}

#bottomHalf {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 990px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #4d3c37;


}
div { /* set div to full width and height */
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
p {
margin-left:2cm; margin-right:2cm;
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you have an overflow:hidden CSS rule on your HTML or body elements

Comment: Can you at least provide us with your websites name?

Comment: @user2350028 How are we supposed to find what the problem is then?

Comment: I provided the code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the `overflow:hidden;` from your `#wrapper` class.

Also, you are using many elements and attributes that are deprecated and not supported anymore as of HTML5, such as `<center>` and `<font>` (as well as attributes like `align`), I'd advise replacing these with their CSS equivalents.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Do you by chance know how I fix the new problem that has popped its head up now?

The bottom of my page looks like this:
http://i.imgur.com/9lq2Hrl.jpg

Comment: How do I extend my div element further down?

Comment: @user2350028 Problem is I can't replicate your problem using the HTML/CSS you've provided in jsFiddle. Try replacing the iFrames height/width attributes with `style="width:100%; height:100%;`

Comment: That just makes it massive. I shrunk the video by a few pixels, and it all seems to fit now. Also, many thanks for the tips on deprecated elements, adjusting font and alignment in CSS makes things a lot easier.